# Interpreting Section object in kernel dump

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, shared-memory

I'm trying to track down issues with a 3thParty application. The path currently being investigated is to look into a Section object that get's created in each process: **rpsPdf10.mutex**.

<sub>If the name of the object is any indication for it's intended usage, I'm not sure why they choose a Section object and use it as a Mutex but that's likely largely irrelevant.</sub>

Using LiveKd I've issued following command's trying to get detailed info of the Section object

```
0: kd>!process 0 0 3thParty.exe
...
PROCESS fffffa800ea80060
    SessionId: 0  Cid: 0a00    Peb: fffdf000  ParentCid: 014c
    DirBase: 99349000  ObjectTable: fffff8a004448bf0  HandleCount: 338.
    Image: 3thParty.exe
...    

0: kd> !handle 0 7 fffffa800ea80060
         ...
         08  fffff8a012e26710 Section                   rpsPdf10.mutex
         ...

0: kd> !object fffff8a012e26710
Object: fffff8a012e26710  Type: (fffffa800cd7cea0) Section
    ObjectHeader: fffff8a012e266e0 (new version)
    HandleCount: 38  PointerCount: 39
    Directory Object: fffff8a00a980080  Name: rpsPdf10.mutex

0: kd> dt nt!_FILE_OBJECT fffff8a012e26710
   +0x000 Type             : 0n256
   +0x002 Size             : 0n0
   +0x008 DeviceObject     : 0x000000000008dfb0 _DEVICE_OBJECT
   +0x010 Vpb              : 0xfffffa80c0000001 _VPB
   +0x018 FsContext        : (null)
   +0x020 FsContext2       : 0xfffffa8000000034 Void
   +0x028 SectionObjectPointer : 0xfffff8a0102d7820 _SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS
   +0x030 PrivateCacheMap  : 0x0000000000001000 Void
   +0x038 FinalStatus      : 0n73728
   +0x040 RelatedFileObject : 0x63536153030a040c _FILE_OBJECT
   +0x048 LockOperation    : 0x74 't'
   +0x049 DeletePending    : 0 ''
   +0x04a ReadAccess       : 0x65 'e'
   +0x04b WriteAccess      : 0 ''
   +0x04c DeleteAccess     : 0x73 's'
   +0x04d SharedRead       : 0 ''
   +0x04e SharedWrite      : 0x74 't'
```

The string `'t' 'e' 's' 't'` in the output definitely sticks out so

- either I'm following a wrong path -> **tx to Blabb, this is certain. It's not a fileobject but the question remains how to find out more information about the Section object. It's still curious and/or a rather unfortunate coincidence that following the section and control area pointers I derived from the fileobject info do seem correct?!**
- or there's something wrong with the Section object
- or ... ?

---

**tldr;**

Following the `_SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS` of the `_FILE_OBJECT` structure above, I arrive at a

- `NumberOfMappedViews` of `0x26` <sub>(= HandleCount: 38)</sub>
- `NumberOfUserReferences` of `0x27` <sub>(= PointerCount: 39)</sub>

so for the moment I assume the path I've followed is correct.

```
0: kd> dt nt!_SECTION_OBJECT_POINTERS 0xfffff8a0102d7820
   +0x000 DataSectionObject : 0xfffffa800fbed900 Void
   +0x008 SharedCacheMap   : 0x0008000000000001 Void
   +0x010 ImageSectionObject : 0x0000000000000001 Void

0: kd> dt nt!_CONTROL_AREA 0xfffffa800fbed900
   +0x000 Segment          : 0xfffff8a0102d7820 _SEGMENT
   +0x008 DereferenceList  : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x0000000000000000 - 0x0000000000000000 ]
   +0x018 NumberOfSectionReferences : 1
   +0x020 NumberOfPfnReferences : 0
   +0x028 NumberOfMappedViews : 0x26
   +0x030 NumberOfUserReferences : 0x27
```

**Edit**

The object header looks like this

```
   0: kd> dt nt!_OBJECT_HEADER fffff8a012e266e0

   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n39
   +0x008 HandleCount      : 0n38
   +0x008 NextToFree       : 0x00000000`00000026 Void
   +0x010 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x018 TypeIndex        : 0x21 '!'
   +0x019 TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x01a InfoMask         : 0xa ''
   +0x01b Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x020 ObjectCreateInfo : 0xfffffa80`0e505140 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x020 QuotaBlockCharged : 0xfffffa80`0e505140 Void
   +0x028 SecurityDescriptor : 0xfffff8a0`1ba076a8 Void
   +0x030 Body             : _QUAD
```

**Edit 2**

following @blabb's answer adjusting for architecture

```
0: kd> ? @$proc
Evaluate expression: -6047068061600 = fffffa80`0ea80060

0: kd> dx (char *)@$proc->ImageFileName
(char *)@$proc->ImageFileName : 0xfffffa800ea80340 : [Type: char *] :  "3thParty.exe"

0: kd> !handle 0 0 @$proc section
...
0474: Object: fffff8a012e26710  GrantedAccess: 000f0007
...

0: kd> !object fffff8a012e26710
Object: fffff8a012e26710  Type: (fffffa800cd7cea0) Section
    ObjectHeader: fffff8a012e266e0 (new version)
    HandleCount: 38  PointerCount: 39
    Directory Object: fffff8a00a980080  Name: rpsPdf10.mutex

0: kd> ?? (unsigned long) (#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_OBJECT_HEADER, Body))
unsigned long 0x30

0: kd> dt nt!_object_header 0xfffff8a012e26710-0x30
   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n39
   +0x008 HandleCount      : 0n38
   +0x008 NextToFree       : 0x00000000`00000026 Void
   +0x010 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x018 TypeIndex        : 0x21 '!'
   +0x019 TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x01a InfoMask         : 0xa ''
   +0x01b Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x020 ObjectCreateInfo : 0xfffffa80`0e505140 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x020 QuotaBlockCharged : 0xfffffa80`0e505140 Void
   +0x028 SecurityDescriptor : 0xfffff8a0`1ba076a8 Void
   +0x030 Body             : _QUAD

0: kd> x nt!ObTypeIndexTable
fffff800`01a70c00 nt!ObTypeIndexTable = <no type information>

0: kd> dt -r1 nt!_SECTION_OBJECT 0xfffff8a012e26710
   +0x000 StartingVa       : 0x00000022`00000100 Void
   +0x008 EndingVa         : 0x00000000`0008dfb0 Void
   +0x010 Parent           : 0xfffffa80`c0000001 Void
   +0x018 LeftChild        : (null) 
   +0x020 RightChild       : 0xfffffa80`00000034 Void
   +0x028 Segment          : 0xfffff8a0`102d7820 _SEGMENT_OBJECT
      +0x000 BaseAddress      : 0xfffffa80`0fbed900 Void
      +0x008 TotalNumberOfPtes : 1
      +0x010 SizeOfSegment    : _LARGE_INTEGER 0x1
      +0x018 NonExtendedPtes  : 0x1000
      +0x01c ImageCommitment  : 0
      +0x020 ControlArea      : (null) 
      +0x028 Subsection       : (null) 
      +0x030 MmSectionFlags   : 0xfffffa80`10987b10 _MMSECTION_FLAGS
      +0x038 MmSubSectionFlags : 0x00000000`03400000 _MMSUBSECTION_FLAGS

0: kd> dc 0xfffff8a012e26710-0x30-0x50
fffff8a0`12e26690  030c0408 f4636553 0e1a02e0 fffffa80  ....Sec.........
fffff8a0`12e266a0  00000048 000000b8 0000001c fffffa80  H...............
fffff8a0`12e266b0  0e505140 fffffa80 00000000 00000000  @QP.............
fffff8a0`12e266c0  0a980080 fffff8a0 001c001c 00000000  ................
fffff8a0`12e266d0  10eb8770 fffff8a0 00000000 00000008  p...............
fffff8a0`12e266e0  00000027 00000000 00000026 00000000  '.......&.......
fffff8a0`12e266f0  00000000 00000000 000a0021 fffff8a0  ........!.......
fffff8a0`12e26700  0e505140 fffffa80 1ba076a8 fffff8a0  @QP......v......

0: kd> !pool 0xfffff8a012e26710-0x30-0x50 2
Pool page fffff8a012e26690 region is Paged pool
*fffff8a012e26690 size:   c0 previous size:   80  (Allocated) *Sect (Protected)
    Pooltag Sect : Section objects
```

Comment: @blabb - *side note: It looks like by using 7 as KMFlags, Windbg ignores the TypeName altogether. Using 0 as KMFlags, it is indeed case sensitive.*

Comment: I have received feedback from the vendor and the Section object's intent is be used as a semaphore. A small amount of memory is reserved and is to be used as a Boolean so it's definitely not a File Object. That said, I'm still curious to dig deeper so any help is welcome.

Comment: i added an answer and deleted the comments take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 32 bit machine running windows 7
Commands used are architecture agnostic but pointer arithmetic are arch dependent

Current process

```
kd> ? @$proc

Evaluate expression: -2061895528 = 8519f898
```

Process Name From EPROCESS->ImageFileName

```
kd> dx  (char *)@$proc->ImageFileName

(char *)@$proc->ImageFileName           : 0xffffffff8519fa04 : "windbg.exe" [Type: char *]
```

lets Search For Some Section Handles in this process
the **TypeName is CaseSensitive**

```
kd> !handle 0 3 @$proc Section

Searching for handles of type Section

PROCESS 8519f898  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0138    Peb: 7ffd8000  ParentCid: 0d04
    DirBase: 7e257560  ObjectTable: b91a3520  HandleCount: 254.
    Image: windbg.exe

Handle table at b91a3520 with 254 entries in use

00c0: Object: 9a10bc58  GrantedAccess: 00000004 Entry: 9945b180
Object: 9a10bc58  Type: (84eb6040) Section
    ObjectHeader: 9a10bc40 (new version)
        HandleCount: 6  PointerCount: 6
```

!handle 0 **3 flag** dumps object specific information which can be reverified using !object {object address}

```
kd> !object 9a10bc58
Object: 9a10bc58  Type: (84eb6040) Section
    ObjectHeader: 9a10bc40 (new version)
    HandleCount: 6  PointerCount: 6
```

each object has an objectheader in 32 bit it is 18 bytes prior to object address  that is sizeof(nt!_OBJECT_HEADER- sizeof(obheader->Body)) body is embedded in HEADER as the last member and is variable sized

```
kd> ?? (unsigned long ) (#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_OBJECT_HEADER , Body))
unsigned long 0x18
```

_OBJECT_HEADER is as follows (though sizes haven't changed  there are differences between new version header and old version header)

```
kd> dt nt!_object_header 9a10bc58-0x18
   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n6
   +0x004 HandleCount      : 0n6
   +0x004 NextToFree       : 0x00000006 Void
   +0x008 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x00c TypeIndex        : 0x21 '!'
   +0x00d TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x00e InfoMask         : 0x8 ''
   +0x00f Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x010 ObjectCreateInfo : 0x82f7aa00 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x010 QuotaBlockCharged : 0x82f7aa00 Void
   +0x014 SecurityDescriptor : (null) 
   +0x018 Body             : _QUAD
```

the old version header had _OBJECT_TYPE directly in the header 
the new version is an index into an array

here the type index is 0x21

the array of Type is at

```
kd> x nt!ObTypeIndexTable
82f88580          nt!ObTypeIndexTable = <no type information>
```

you can write a script like this to dump all the types

```
function log(instr)
{
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(instr + "\n");
}
function exec (cmdstr)
{
    return host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand(cmdstr);
}
function dumptypeindex()
{
    var cpob    = host.createPointerObject
    var titab   = exec("x nt!ObTypeIndexTable").First().substr(0,8)
    var obtype  = cpob(host.parseInt64(titab , 16),"nt","_OBJECT_TYPE **")
    var i = 2
    while(obtype[i] !=0 )
    {
        log("index = "+i+"\t"+ host.memory.readWideString(obtype[i].Name.Buffer))
        i++
    }
}
```

executing this script would yield the types as follows

```
kd> .scriptload c:\wdscr\dumptypeindex.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'c:\dumptypeindex.js'
kd> dx @$scriptContents.dumptypeindex()
index = 2   Type
index = 3   Directory
index = 4   SymbolicLink
index = 5   Token
index = 6   Job
index = 7   Process
index = 8   Thread
index = 9   UserApcReserve
index = 10  IoCompletionReserve
index = 11  DebugObject
index = 12  Event
index = 13  EventPair
index = 14  Mutant
index = 15  Callback
index = 16  Semaphore
index = 17  Timer
index = 18  Profile
index = 19  KeyedEvent
index = 20  WindowStation
index = 21  Desktop
index = 22  TpWorkerFactory
index = 23  Adapter
index = 24  Controller
index = 25  Device
index = 26  Driver
index = 27  IoCompletion
index = 28  File
index = 29  TmTm
index = 30  TmTxȂ؃扏楄
index = 31  TmRm
index = 32  TmEn
index = 33  Section
index = 34  Session
index = 35  Key
index = 36  ALPC Port
index = 37  PowerRequest
index = 38  WmiGuid
index = 39  EtwRegistration
index = 40  EtwConsumer
index = 41  FilterConnectionPort
index = 42  FilterCommunicationPort
index = 43  PcwObject
```

notice 0x21 = 0n33 = Section

given that we have a Section

we can dump the Section Object

```
kd> dt -r1 nt!_SECTION_OBJECT 9a10bc58
   +0x000 StartingVa       : 0x90f87b44 Void
   +0x004 EndingVa         : 0x82efb58a Void
   +0x008 Parent           : 0xc0802000 Void
   +0x00c LeftChild        : (null) 
   +0x010 RightChild       : 0xc0c0a280 Void
   +0x014 Segment          : 0x995ed8d8 _SEGMENT_OBJECT
      +0x000 BaseAddress      : 0x86b65740 Void
      +0x004 TotalNumberOfPtes : 0xdf
      +0x008 SizeOfSegment    : _LARGE_INTEGER 0x000000df`00080000
      +0x010 NonExtendedPtes  : 0xdf000
      +0x014 ImageCommitment  : 0
      +0x018 ControlArea      : (null) 
      +0x01c Subsection       : (null) 
      +0x020 MmSectionFlags   : 0x869f52a8 _MMSECTION_FLAGS
      +0x024 MmSubSectionFlags : 0x02ea0000 _MMSUBSECTION_FLAGS
```

an object is preceded by object header which is preceded by the pool_header

```
kd> dc 9a10bc58-0x18-0x18
9a10bc28  060b0204 f4636553 00000720 00000070  ....Sec. ...p...
9a10bc38  00000000 00000000 00000006 00000006  ................
9a10bc48  00000000 00080021 82f7aa00 00000000  ....!...........
9a10bc58  90f87b44 82efb58a c0802000 00000000  D{....... ......
9a10bc68  c0c0a280 995ed8d8 000df000 00000000  ......^.........
9a10bc78  00012000 00000004 0670020b 6666744e  . ........p.Ntff
9a10bc88  00f00702 00000a48 0000c0fe 00020000  ....H...........
9a10bc98  00000000 00000002 00000000 00000000  ................
```

notice the Sec tag Sect is used by SectionObjects

```
d> !pool 9a10bc58-0x18-0x18 2
Pool page 9a10bc28 region is Paged pool
*9a10bc28 size:   58 previous size:   20  (Allocated) *Sect (Protected)
        Pooltag Sect : Section objects
```

Comment: *fwiw - I'm working from a kernel dump and using Windbg 10.0.10240.9. The `!handle 0 3 @$proc Section` returns me everything and ignores the type. `!handle 0 0 @$proc Section` only returns sections* (still ploughing through your answer)

Comment: i am using @$proc as an example if your current process is not the process with exception you may need to change context with .process / p /r {addr of EPROCESS (returned from !process 0 0 exeofinterest)}  the walkthrough was   done from a insider preview windbg 16278

Comment: No, `@$proc` is correct, just pointing out something about Windbg *you* might not know after getting bombarded with things *I* didn't know ;)

Comment: So it's established that it's a Section object. What tripped me up is Process Explorer showing this as being of type Section and offering a description of *A memory mapped file or paging-file backed memory region*. I assumed it was a FILE_OBJECT.

Comment: Stupid question perhas but do you happen to know how to get to the content of the section?

Comment: can you make that a separate question  posting too much info in one answer would make it gibberish

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745973/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-section-object-in-a-kernel-dump) and thanks for educating me. I have the Windows Internals books with me but I find it very difficult to know what pointers to follow and to what they point to. Can I ask where you get all that information?

Comment: done take a look and most of the information is derived by debugging the debugger and their extension commands which  throw out  errors because of ms developing the extension with private pdb and the commands not working with public pdbs